# FetchJson stopped he’s work for no reason

Tags: ios, json, swift, rest, codable

I am getting data from news API. Everything was working like 40+ times then something happened and nothing was working. After I turn on mac on next day it worked a few times and now again doesn’t, I don't know why is this. please help, code is below :

I tried to reinstall Xcode, manage some plist, rewrite the project.

```
struct Model: Codable {
    let articles: [News]
}

struct Source: Codable {
    var name: String?
    var id: String?
}

struct News: Codable {
    var title: String?
    var url: String
    var description: String
    var urlToImage: URL?
    var source: Source
    var publishedAt: String?
    var author: String?
    var content: String?
}


class myData {
    static func getData(completion: @escaping ([News]) -> ()) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
            var finalData = [News]()

            let jsonUrlString = "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=ua&apiKey=0cff1368c1d1445d9a0bccb6063a5220"
            if let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) {
                if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {

                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    if let jsonPetitions = try? decoder.decode(Model.self, from: data) {
                        finalData = jsonPetitions.articles
                    }
                }
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(finalData)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

my code is reloading tableView and every time it comes empty. it should look like simple json.

Comment: Never use `Data(contentsOf:)` for remote resources. Download the data using `URLSession`, then you'll be able to see and handle any errors that might occur.

Comment: it doesn't helped i tried code with urlSessions but it doesn't even go to cathc so i jsut recieve an empty array

Comment: Don't just look at caught errors, also inspect the error parameter from the URLSessionTask closure.

Comment: Define stopped working: `finalData` empty? There are 2 try not caught ? Any logs?

Comment: Try deducing the error in catch block using `try Data(contentsOf: url)` instead of `try? Data(contentsOf: url)`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a decoding error. It'll be easily deducible if you catch the decoding error. The `description` property is null for one of the news source in your response. Just make it `Optional`.

Try this:

```
struct Model: Codable {
    let articles: [News]
}

struct Source: Codable {
    var name: String?
    var id: String?
}

struct News: Codable {
    var title: String?
    var url: String
    var description: String?
    var urlToImage: String?
    var source: Source
    var publishedAt: String?
    var author: String?
    var content: String?
}


class MyData {
    static func getData(completion: @escaping ([News]) -> ()) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
            var finalData = [News]()

            let jsonUrlString = "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=ua&apiKey=0cff1368c1d1445d9a0bccb6063a5220"
            if let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) {

                do {
                    let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url)

                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    let jsonPetitions = try decoder.decode(Model.self, from: data!)
                    finalData = jsonPetitions.articles
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }


            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(finalData)
            }
        }
    }
}

MyData.getData { (news) in
    print(news)
}
```